# How can I add elements with an (click) function in Angular per code?

Tags: angular, typescript, function, onclick, innerhtml

I am searching a way to add elements in Angular per Typescript Code. The problem is, that these elements should have a (click) function and I don't know, how many of these elements should be added (for example a for loop with any range should create any amount of elements).

```
textausgabe.innerHTML += '<div (click)="caller()"'>click</div>';
```

This created the element correctly, but if I click on it, nothing happens.

Do you know a way to solve my problem, than please show me how :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this in angular. Add an array in your ts file and use `*ngFor` to loop over that array in your template. In your `(click)` handler you can then just append an element to that array. `*ngFor` will take care of creating that element for you.

*template.html*

```
<div *ngFor="let element of elements" (click)="caller()">click</div>
<button (click)="appendElement()">Append Element</button>
```

*component.ts*

```
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
   public elements:Array<unknown> = [];

   public appendElement():void {
      this.elements = [...this.elements, this.elements.length + 1]; // Just append anything, since you are not using the values otherwise, appending a generic ID here
   }

   public caller():void {
      // Do whatever you want when your appended elements are clicked
   }
}
```

Here a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqenzr).